# WCF Discovery with load balanced end points

Tags: wcf, ws-discovery

I have the following scenario:

I have a master controlling WCF application that allows different client applications to communicate with one another. It finds the clients that want to communicate with each other using WCF discovery. Something like shown below:

```
[Client Prod 1] <--> [Controller] <--> [Client Prod 2]
```

All works fine however I was just informed that the client's prod environment is using a load balancer between my controller and the client apps:

```
[Client Prod 1-1]                                                             [Client Prod 2-1]
[Client Prod 1-2] <--> Load Balancer <--> [Controller] <--> Load Balancer <--> [Client Prod 2-2]
[Client Prod 1-3]
```

When the client product 1 does it's "Hello" announcement, will WCF register 3 separate prod 1's or will it just register the load balancer?

(Additional information: .NET 4 and IIS 7.5)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question so you probably have the answer already. Still...

Discovery is based on UDP. If Load Balancers on your picture puts CP1s in a different subnet, discovery won't work at all. However if all servers are in the same subnet then either controller may launch discovery and locate all CP1s or all CP1s must announce their presence and thus be registered by Controller.